# How do I convert html text to organized json array?

Tags: jquery, json

I've got 2 html divs I need to loop through their html and format in a specific way.

```
//Desired output

    { 
    "nameoffirstcategory" : {a , b, c, d, e, f},
    "nameofsecondcategory" : {a , b , c ,d ,e,f} 
    }
```

This is the html of the two check box columns.

```
      <h5>Preview</h5>
              <div class="row">
                 <div class="col tms-check-column">
                    <label class="informationTitle" id="topic-preview-left">Topic Example Left</label>
                    <div id="p-example-left">
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col tms-check-column">
                    <label class="informationTitle" id="topic-preview-right">Topic Example Right</label>
                    <div id="p-example-right">
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
              <p class="tms-autosaved-txt">AutoSaved</p>
              <button onclick="saveAllItems();" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Auto Save</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
           </div>
```

I've tried pushing the values to an array called values in .each loops. but my format is like this

```
// output I get from my javascript.

    [{"titlel":"Topic Example Left"},
     {"check":"Cash or self-payment"},
     {"check":"Medicaid"},

     {"titler":"Topic Example Right"},
     {"check":"Persons with co-occurring mental and substance abuse},
     {"check":"Active duty military"}]
```

Here I loop through the columns fine and get all the data I need. The problem is the json output is not formatted correctly like the desired output above.

```
    // my javascript function

    function saveAllItems() {

        let values = [];

        titlel = jQuery("#topic-preview-left").text();
        titler = jQuery("#topic-preview-right").text();

        values.push({
            titlel: titlel
        });

        // left column text
        jQuery("#p-example-left > p").each(function() {

            let check = jQuery(this).html();
            values.push({
                check: check
            });

        });

        values.push({
            titler: titler
        });


        // right column text
        jQuery("#p-example-right > p").each(function() {
            let check = jQuery(this).html();

            values.push({
                check: check
            });
        });

        let json = JSON.stringify(values);
        console.log(json);


    }
```

Comment: Some according to your content, what actually you want  `{nameoffirstcategory :{"titlel":"Topic Example Left"},
     {"check":"Cash or self-payment"},
     {"check":"Medicaid"},

  nameofsecondcategory: {"titler":"Topic Example Right"},
     {"check":"Persons with co-occurring mental and substance abuse},
     {"check":"Active duty military"}}`     So this is what you want or not?

Comment: I need the json format to be. I have no clue how to do this.
    { 
    "category left title" : {item1 , item2 , item3},
    "category right title" : {item1 , item2 , item3} 
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with a nested loop, like this:

```js
function saveAllItems() {
    var values = {};
    jQuery("[id*=topic-preview]").each(function () {
        var $items = jQuery("div[id*=p-example] > p", $(this).parent());
        values[jQuery(this).text()] = $items.map(function () {
            return jQuery(this).text();
        }).get();
    });
    console.log(values);
}
saveAllItems();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col tms-check-column">
    <label class="informationTitle" id="topic-preview-left">Topic Example Left</label>
    <div id="p-example-left">
        <p>a</p>
        <p>b</p>
        <p>c</p>
        <p>d</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col tms-check-column">
    <label class="informationTitle" id="topic-preview-right">Topic Example Right</label>
    <div id="p-example-right">
        <p>g</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a great answer it works exactly how I want when I run your code. Only problem is when I run it on my html exactly it returns this {  
   "Payment":[  

   ],
   "Special Programs":[  

   ],
   "left dynamic five":[  
      "Cash or self-payment",
      "Medicaidd",
      "Medicare",
   ],
   "right dynamic three":[  
      "Persons with co-occurring mental and substance abuse disorders", 
      "Persons with eating disorders"
   ]
}

Comment: OK, so you have other elements with the same class. Maybe this selector will not match those other elements? `jQuery("[id*=topic-preview]").each(...`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an array for values, use object and add the values to the object.
When adding items to object first check if the value for the key is undefined if not append to existing value with a comma if it can be string as below.
Also in case if it can be array we can push the values to the property.

Something like:

```
 var values = {};

 if(values.title1){
   values.title1 =  values.title1 + ',' +title1;
  }
else{
  values.title1 = title1;
}

 // if array then,

var values = {};

 if(values.title1 && values.title1.length > 0 ){
   values.title1.push(title1)
  }
else{
  values.title1 = [title1];
}
```

Same way when pushing check property as well.

Answer (score 1):

According to the HTML provided in the question, you can traverse over the `label`s and get the text from the next `div` element. Like below:-

```
$(function() {
    const data = $('[id*="topic-preview-"]').map(function(index, elem) {
        return {
            [$(this).attr('id').replace(/-/g, '')]: $(this).next().text().trim()
        }
    }).get();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  const data = $('[id*="topic-preview-"]').map(function(index, elem) {
    return {
      [$(this).attr('id').replace(/-/g, '')]: $(this).next().text().trim()
    }
  }).get();
  
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col tms-check-column">
    <label class="informationTitle" id="topic-preview-left">Topic Example Left</label>
    <div id="p-example-left">item list</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col tms-check-column">
    <label class="informationTitle" id="topic-preview-right">Topic Example Right</label>
    <div id="p-example-right">item list</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, according to your requirement, I try to create structure as you have and kind of modify your code, so that you can understand easily.

---

```
<div id="topic-preview-left">
Topic Example Left  
</div>
<div id="p-example-left">
<p>Topic Example Left</p>
<p>Medicaid</p>
</div>
<div id="topic-preview-right">
Topic Example right  
</div>
<div id="p-example-right">
<p>Topic Example right</p>
<p>Active duty military</p>
</div>
```

---

```
   var leftKey  = $("#topic-preview-left").text();
var rightKey = $("#topic-preview-right").text();

var pLeftExamples = [];
  $("#p-example-left > p").each(function() {
            pLeftExamples.push($(this).html());
        });
var pRightExamples = [];
$("#p-example-right > p").each(function() {
  pRightExamples.push($(this).html());
});    

var mainObject = {};
mainObject[leftKey] = pLeftExamples;
mainObject[rightKey] = pRightExamples;
console.log(mainObject);
```

Output:

```
{…}
​
"
Topic Example Left  
": Array [ "Topic Example Left", "Medicaid" ]
​
"
Topic Example right  
": Array [ "Topic Example right", "Active duty military" ]
​
```

Link of jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dupinderdhiman/b3zevumk/51/

have a look, if not understanding anything, let me know, i will explain